# Leetcode выдает ошибку выхода за пределы массива

Tags: c#

В LeetCode выдает странную ошибку (Index was outside the bounds of the array) при обращении к размерности массива массивов *matrix.Length*. Как тогда узнать размерность массива?

```
 public class Solution {
    public bool SearchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
        if(matrix.Length == 0)
            return false;
        int n = matrix.Length;
        ....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в последнем изменении индекса какая-то глупость написана, которая очевидно выдаёт выход за пределы массива

Comment: Ну и условие в цикле всегда true

Comment: @AlexeyTen, он на первом if выдает при обращении к matrix.Length, я же написал

Comment: Не верю. Хотя бы потому что там вообще нет никаких индексов.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, посмотрите скрин

Comment: Уберите из кода обращение к элементам массива. Есть ощущение, что диагностика просто не на ту строку ссылается.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, действительно так, спасибо)